# Force Close loop.. need help

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, force-close

I have a force close loop on my galaxy s2.

I want to retrieve my data which isnt stored on an sd card.
But I cannot get into my phone.

I tried plugging into my laptop but it doesnt pick up the phone.
I tried booting in safe mode to disable the apps. But the phone just turns off again even in safe mode.

I dont care about the phone, only the data, which I stupidly havnt backed up anywhere.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you care about data, its a good practice to backup always.
In your case, anyway, you don't have backup available with you. So, the only option available for you to avoid 'force close loop' is to goto recovery and flash it with the appropriate rom. Please note that you will lose all the data present on your sdcard, however, the data present in memory card would remain intact.

Answer (score 0):

If you have flashed a custom recovery, you can access the files on the internal `/data` partition from the recovery through ADB.

I have found [this](http://galaxys2root.com/cwmtwrp-recovery/) site; there are recovery images which can be flashed via ODIN if you didn't already install a recovery; as far as I know it doesn't wipe internal data.

When you're in the recovery, connect your phone to your PC. Install ADB on your PC, then you can use `adb shell` to log in to your phone and look around in the file system; then you can `adb pull` the interesting files.